# Using stdlib.h within a device driver

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

I am trying to write a device driver and I need to use `system()` function in the driver. To use `system()` we need to include `<stdlib.h>`, which dosnt seem to work from a driver.

It says no such file or directory found.

Is there an alternative to `stdlib.h` for device drivers? Or an alternative to `system()`?

Comment: Since a driver does not run as a particular user, what exactly should `system` do in this case? Run a shell as root? Since `system` does quite a bit of setup, it may not be the best choice to put that code in the kernel.

Comment: You may need to consider a daemon process in the user-space that interacts with your driver.

Comment: Calling system sounds like a baaad idea.

Comment: if it says no such file found, it does not mean that `<stdlib.h>` does not work from a driver

Comment: @mangusta That's right. You're in kernel space, the facilities for normal user space applications are not available. You cannot call system() in the kernel. There is no suitable alternative.

Comment: This sounds like a typical [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @nos oh, now I see. mostly `linux/*.h` are used in drivers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

stdlib.h is a user space header.

User space is that set of memory locations in which user processes (i.e., everything other than the kernel) run. A process is an executing instance of a program. One of the roles of the kernel is to manage individual user processes within this space and to prevent them from interfering with each other.

Kernel space can be accessed by user processes only through the use of system calls. System calls are requests in a Unix-like operating system by an active process for a service performed by the kernel, such as input/output (I/O) or process creation. An active process is a process that is currently progressing in the CPU, as contrasted with a process that is waiting for its next turn in the CPU. I/O is any program, operation or device that transfers data to or from a CPU and to or from a peripheral device (such as disk drives, keyboards, mice and printers).

Please check KERNEL DIRECTORY/include folder for what headers can be used in kernel space.

There is no alternative to system command.

Once possible solution is that you can create a sys /proc entry from the kernel space to set a flag, from the user space you can check the flag and use system().

Comment: It is not strictly speaking true that "there is no alternative to system command" as it actually is *possible* to create a userspace process from the kernel.  However it is indeed generally *inadvisable*.

Answer (score 3):

The fact that you're attempting to #include stdlib.h and use system() from a driver shows that you need to become more educated about kernel-mode programming. So, before attempting any of this, you really ought to understand why that header doesn't exist in the kernel environment and why you can't use the libc system() function from there.

However, that being said, there *is* a kernel-mode analog that can be used when it makes sense to do so:

```
#include <linux.kmod.h>

static char *envv[] = {
    "PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin",
    "HOME=/",
    NULL
};
static char *argv[] = {
    "/sbin/your_program",
    "arg1",
    ...
    "argn",
    NULL
};

int status = call_usermodehelper(argv[0], argv, envv, UMH_NO_WAIT);
```

There are other UMH_xxx flags that allow you to wait on the process to complete as system() would do. It would be well to understand what that means in the context of your driver (or any driver) before doing so.